# Importing sounddevice to python crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, python-sounddevice

I am trying to import the sounddevice module in python, but whenever I am doing that it seems to crash? I have tried older versions of sounddevice, but still the same issue. I am running Python 3.7.5. This is what the log looks like:

```
C:\>python
Python 3.7.5 (tags/v3.7.5:5c02a39a0b, Oct 15 2019, 00:11:34) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sounddevice

C:\>
```

Has anybody experienced this before?

Thanks!

Comment: i just tried and it works fine, no crash !!! tell about your system it is 86x or 64xbit ? and which python installer you used?

Comment: @MayurSatav I am running 64bit Windows 10, and used the python installer from python. Module was installed via pip

Comment: Could you please try running it in a debugger (line by line) to find out which line causes the crash?

Comment: @Matthias I tried doing the same with PyCharm and I got this `Process finished with exit code -1073741786 (0xC0000026)` Nothing more

Comment: Could you please try running it in PyCharm's debugger (line by line) to find out which line causes the crash?

Comment: @Matthias I did that, but got the same output

Comment: At which line did the crash occur?

Comment: @Matthias I am just getting the same `Process finished with exit code -1073741786 (0xC0000026)` Here is a video demo, maybe I am doing it incorrectly? [debug video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwJX1mIhxqA)

Comment: I guess you should set a breakpoint before starting the debugger? Then you should be able to step through the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well.  Rather strangely it resolved itself after I installed pyaudio.  They both rely on portaudio underneath and I wonder if something is missing in sounddevice's package.  Sounddevice continued to work even after I uninstalled pyaudio. You might need to install pyaudio from this well respected repository: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
You need to make sure you get the file with cp37 since that is for python 3.7
You would navigate to the correct folder and do `pip install filename`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I did try this, but it was still the same issue. :(

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out.  If you find another solution, I would be happy to know as well.  It is a good question.  Maybe if you ran the program another way, perhaps an IDE, then there would be a bigger error message for us to look at.

Comment: I tried the same with PyCharm and got this. `Process finished with exit code -1073741786 (0xC0000026)`

Nothing more!

Answer (score 0):

I also have been running into this issue lately. Simply running "import sounddevice" would crash Python. **Downgrading sounddevice to 0.3.8 fixed this issue for me.**

If I attach a debugger, the crash reports

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDBD20CB98 (InProcessClient64.dll) in python.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

>   InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd20cb98()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd20cb2d()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd20cb49()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd2128b2()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd1b705b()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd17bf89()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd1a6a29()    Unknown
    InProcessClient64.dll!00007ffdbd17bea8()    Unknown
    _cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd!00007ffd8d860258() Unknown
    _cffi_backend.cp36-win_amd64.pyd!PyInit__cffi_backend() + 6948 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyCFunction_FastCallDict() + 386 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() + 899 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 969 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!_Py_CheckFunctionResult() + 779 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!PyOS_FSPath() + 565 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!PyOS_FSPath() + 279 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 13746 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!_Py_CheckFunctionResult() + 779 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() + 2031 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 969 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() + 1374 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 969 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() + 1374 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 969 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs() + 1374 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 969 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyFunction_FastCallDict() + 218 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyObject_FastCallDict() + 321 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs() + 176 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject() + 529 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault() + 12700 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!_Py_CheckFunctionResult() + 779 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!PyEval_EvalCodeEx() + 155 bytes    Unknown
    python36.dll!PyEval_EvalCode() + 45 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!PyArena_Free() + 167 bytes Unknown
    python36.dll!PyRun_InteractiveOneObject() + 715 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags() + 240 bytes   Unknown
    python36.dll!PyRun_AnyFileExFlags() + 69 bytes  Unknown
    python36.dll!00000000537caf44() Unknown
    python36.dll!000000005374e57a() Unknown
    python.exe!000000001c1a126d()   Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 20 bytes   Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() + 33 bytes   Unknown
```

I haven't been able to determine why this occurs, but downgrading sounddevice has fixed it. For me personally, sounddevice 0.3.8 is the last one that works

```
C:\>python -m pip install sounddevice==
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sounddevice== (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.3.10, 0.3.11, 0.3.12, 0.3.13, 0.3.14, 0.3.15, 0.4.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sounddevice==

C:\>python -m pip install sounddevice==0.4.0
Collecting sounddevice==0.4.0
Installing collected packages: sounddevice
Successfully installed sounddevice-0.4.0

C:\>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sounddevice

C:\>python -m pip install sounddevice==0.3.9
Collecting sounddevice==0.3.9
Installing collected packages: sounddevice
  Attempting uninstall: sounddevice
    Found existing installation: sounddevice 0.4.0
    Uninstalling sounddevice-0.4.0:
      Successfully uninstalled sounddevice-0.4.0
Successfully installed sounddevice-0.3.9

C:\>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sounddevice

C:\>python -m pip install sounddevice==0.3.8
Collecting sounddevice==0.3.8
Installing collected packages: sounddevice
  Attempting uninstall: sounddevice
    Found existing installation: sounddevice 0.3.9
    Uninstalling sounddevice-0.3.9:
      Successfully uninstalled sounddevice-0.3.9
Successfully installed sounddevice-0.3.8

C:\>python
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sounddevice
>>> exit()

C:\>
```